# Socket programming in java - Sharing server data

Tags: java, sockets

I want to have multiple clients communicating via a server AND for the clients to be able to affect each other via what information they pass to the server (like a chat maybe).

Background:
I am working on an assignment in regards to socket programming in Java, with a server and multiple clients, and since it is an assignment I will refer to public documentation to describe my problem. The assignment is to write a game and it has been going quite well. To set up the sockets I have been following the format from this tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

In the documentation above we have one server that keeps calling a serverThread object, using the accept() method to establish contact with a client that connects. The server is just listening and creating threads for the clients to hop in, we also have an object that is a protocol of communication but I don't mind that for now. All in all the documentation provides the following classes:

1. KKMultiServer (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServer.java)
2. KnockKnockClient (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockClient.java)
3. KKMultiThread (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KKMultiServerThread.java)
4. (KKProtocol)

Problem:

I have managed to write a game that works very well, but here is my problem, every client is in isolation within their own thread. I want multiple clients to be able to interact with each other via the server, if player 1 moves it should update the screen for player 2, and vice versa is my intention. Right now, if multiple clients connect to the serverThread it is as if they are in two separate games, which is not what I want.

In the java documentation above we can have the same problem, with KnockKnock jokes. I want one client to be able to write something, and then for the server to pass on to another client what the first client wrote. However, how can we have data from one client that can be passed to another client via the server, if they are all isolated in different threads (as per the documentation)?

Comment: “then for the server to pass on to another client what the first client wrote” This is exactly the solution. In order the server to communicate back to the client, you need to keep a reference of the thread. You have n client connected you should have n KKMultiServerThread.

Comment: Threads aren't isolated. At all. You can just have a list of all clients.

Comment: But note that accessing stuff with more than one thread at the same time is a bit of a recipe for *intermittent* crashes. You should use synchronization to make sure only one thread is doing stuff at a time (while the other ones are waiting for the client to send data)

Comment: Thank you guys. I followed the first suggestion here with keeping a reference and that did the trick (and that reference holds the clients connected so we can see the other player). I found a multi-client chat from scratch on Youtube and in that the implementation was to pass a reference of the server to the thread upon accepting the socket from the client. The threads could with this reference pass information via the server. Perhaps a recipe for crashes but I think its quite sufficient for this lab at least. 

Thanks guys, this was  a bad question but you helped me out, all the best.

Comment: i don't think it will work in your game, but you can just implement a queue where all the events are sent and broadcasted to everybody. If you have topics implemented, you could even create separate games within the same server